# How to pass value from PHP to JS?

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

After

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->_request->getBaseUrl() . '/public/scripts/czassesji.js', 'text/javascript');
```

is called script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var licznik = 0;
  var aktywny = true;
  window.onblur = function(){aktywny = false;};
  window.onfocus = function(){aktywny = true; licznik = 0;};

  var id = setInterval(function(){wyslijImpuls()},60000);

  function wyslijImpuls() {
    if(aktywny == false) {
      licznik++;  //żeby nie tracić czasu spędzonego na stronie (np: 30 sekund), gdy uzytkownik przelączy okno/zakładkę przeglądarki
    }
    if(licznik < 2) {
      $.post(baseUrl+'Zapiszczas/', {'ile': 1});
    }
  }
  $.post(baseUrl+'Zapiszczas/', {'ile': 1});
  console.log(baseUrl);
});
```

and I revieved error

> ReferenceError: baseUrl is not defined $.post(baseUrl+'Zapiszczas/',
>   {'ile': 1});

My question is how to pass `baseUrl` value to js? I'd like to mentioned that `baseUrl` is defined in `config.ini` and accessible in php Zend controller.

Comment: Did you search before post your question?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: use this. var baseUrl = '<?php echo 'somethinglike this';?>';

Comment: I can not put php directli into js script.

Comment: @Tomasz you do that on the document, not in an external script. It will become a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save that baseURL in some input hidden or in a global var in javascript, when php send the rended page , javascript can't access to php variables, one is executed in server side and the other is exectued in the client side.

```
<script>
baseURL = this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->_request->getBaseUrl() . '/public/scripts/czassesji.js', 'text/javascript');
</scrip>
```

And then call in your next javascript script.

Answer (score 0):

At the very Top of your ViewScript where you added $this->view->headScript()

```
//VIEW FILE 
<?php
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->_request->getBaseUrl() . '/public/scripts/czassesji.js', 'text/javascript');
    //TRY ADDING THIS:
    $this->inlineScript()->captureStart();
        echo "var baseURL = '" . $baseUrl . "';";
    $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd();
    //.... MORE CODES...
?>

  <?php 
   // IN YOUR CONTROLLER: SINCE YOU HAVE ACCESS TO THE $baseUrl VARIABLE HERE
   // TRY THIS IN THE APPROPRIATE ACTION:

    public function showAction(){
        //...HANDLE YOUR BUSINESS LOGIC 

        $arrViewModel               = array();
        $arrViewModel['baseUrl']    = $pointerToBaseURL;
        $viewModel                  = new ViewModel($arrViewModel);
        //IF $viewModel ALREADY EXIST BEFORE THIS POINT:
        // YOU MAY JUST ADD THE baseUrl KEY LIKE SO 
        // $viewModel->setVariable('baseUrl',  '$pointerToBaseURL');           
        return $viewModel;
    }
    ?>

// IN YOUR JQUERY... $baseUrl SHOULD NOW BE AVAILABLE 
// SINCE IT IS NOW GLOBALLY SCOPED FROM YOUR VIEW:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var licznik = 0;
var aktywny = true;
window.onblur = function(){aktywny = false;};
window.onfocus = function(){aktywny = true; licznik = 0;};

var id = setInterval(function(){wyslijImpuls()},60000);

function wyslijImpuls() {
    if(aktywny == false) {
        licznik++;  //żeby nie tracić czasu spędzonego na stronie (np: 30 sekund), gdy uzytkownik przelączy okno/zakładkę przeglądarki
    }
    if(licznik < 2) {
        $.post(baseUrl+'Zapiszczas/', {'ile': 1});
    }
}
$.post(baseUrl+'Zapiszczas/', {'ile': 1});
    console.log(baseUrl);
```

});

I hope this helps a bit...